# Storing ancillary support packages within a visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, package

I was wondering about the right way to do this.  For example, let's say you have a number of projects (part of a solution) that uses boost.  Let's say you want to put the boost package in the solution so the entire thing is more portable.

How do you do that?  Do you install boost in a directory within the solution? Can you reference it using relative directories, so it isn't portable?

Under Linux, for completeness, one could just store a tarball in the code under control, but it was left to the developer to bring it out and install it.  I'm wondering how this is done (best practices) under visual studio.

[NOTE:  I understand this might make the solution large, but the benefit would be a development environment that would run immediately without a bunch of package installs for each development system accessing the code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use the nuget package manager in visual studio to add the nuget boost package to your solution then boost will be available to the projects that need it. You can then enable package restore so that whenever the solution is built if the boost files are missing from the solution then nuget will restore them on build.

If you haven't already you will need to install the nuget package manager plugin for visual studio.

Where the package isn't available on nuget there are a number of options; you can build the package and then reference the assembly that's been built - you just store assemblies you need in a references directory. If your using source control software Svn or tfs possibly git ( I don't know) then you can store these in source control and then include them in the target solution via links. The final option I can think of is you can build the package into a nuget package and then store the result in your own private nuget store visual studio allows for this. Which solution works for you will depend on the size of the project, development team and the source control software you use.

Comment: OK, but the boost was just an example.  What if it's a package not available on nuget, but has to be downloaded an built separately?  I am aware of how helpful nuget is in managing standard packages.